# RoR select with options_for_select and static values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this select:

```
<%= f.select :operator_id, options_for_select(@tecnici.collect{ |tec| [tec.nome, tec.id] }, (params[:action] == 'edit' || params[:action] == 'update' ? @work.operator_id : 0 ) ), {include_blank: 'Me Medesimo'}, class: 'form-control' %>
```

using "options_for_select" i can retrieve options velues from db, but i need to add a static value (non blank!) to the options list, but i can't find how i can do it!

Can someone help me?

Thanks to all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add it to the collection.  If that feels a little hackish, you can create a method that will return the array to be turned into an option list.

```
([['Static', 'static'],['Another', 'another']] + @tecnici.collect{...})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add them to the array before passing it to `options_for_select`.

```
options_for_select(@tecnici.collect { |tec| [tec.nome, tec.id] } + [['My item 1', 'item_1_id'], ['My item 2', 'item_2_id']],...
```

Of course the options preparation code is best placed to a helper function.